# Expo React Native -EAS build is not working

Tags: react-native, expo

When I try to run EAS build, I'll always get the same error.

```
Compressing project files and uploading to EAS Build. Learn more
    Error: EPERM: operation not 
    permitted, scandir 
    '/Users/Sergio/.Trash'
    Code: EPERM
```

I already tried clearing the cache and did change the permission via "System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access" and then select the terminal.

But still the same issue. Does anyone have a solution for this error?